# Openapi 6.6.0 / 7 maven plugin for spring does not generate import statement for @JsonIgnoreProperties

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

In both versions openapi  6.6.0 / 7 maven spring generator with schema having discriminator, generates @JsonIgnoreProperties but the java file does have import statement for com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties  . Any workaround available?

I tried to importMappings but did not work